# Javascript empty field validations are not working

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to make some empty field input validations but they are not working at all. I've tried using .length, equals to 0, and equals to null, but none of them do the job. Any idea why it is?
Here´s the code:

```
if (this.subscriberform.callForward.onBusy) {
        console.log(
          "MSISDNOnBusy",
          this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy
        );
        if (this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy) {
          if (this.subscriberform.profile.starDial.callForward) {
            if (
              this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.match(
                this.subscriberform.starDial.regex
              ) === null
            ) {
              this.errorMessageAlert(
                "Busy MSISDN does not match call forwarding regular expressions."
              );
              // console.log(this.errorMessageAlert)
              // return;
            } 
            if (this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy==="" || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy===null
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy===0 || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length===""
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length===0 || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length==null
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length==0 || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length==""
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length==null || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy=="" 
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy==null || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy==0
            ) {
              this.errorMessageAlert(
                "Busy MSISDN must not be empty"
                );
              return;
            }
          }
        }
        // else {
        //   this.errorMessageAlert("Busy MSISDN must not be empty.");
        //   return;
        // }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Half of your checks in this block:

```
if (this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy==="" || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy===null
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy===0 || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length===""
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length===0 || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length==null
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length==0 || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length==""
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy.length==null || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy=="" 
            || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy==null || this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy==0
            )
```

don't really mean anything.

Assuming that `msisdnOnBusy` is a string, at the very start of your example, you have this check:

```
if (this.subscriberform.callForward.msisdnOnBusy) {
```

So it's already "truthy", so your big if block towards the end will never return true. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

As an empty string is considered "falsy" in js, `msisdnOnBusy` contains something - a simple `console.log()` will tell you what

**Edit for question "How could I change my validations for the empty field?"**

I'd need to know more about what you're trying to do, what `callForward` is, and if `msisdnOnBusy` is actually a string before I could say for sure. In general, your first step is ensuring the HTML is correct. For example, adding the `required` attribute to your input like so:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
```

Means that you get basic form validation and it won't submit unless `username` is filled in.

Obviously we can't trust the client, though, so some extra validation is called for:

```
const username = document.getElementById('username').value.trim();
if(!username) {
    console.error(`No username; show an alert`)
}
```

Here, we get the value of the `username` input, call `trim()` on it to remove any leading or trailing whitespace, then make our check.

Again, this is most likely on the client side, so you'd probably need additional checks on the server if you're using this for anything important.

You should be able to adapt this to your example

Comment: So... it's already a "true"... How could I change my validations for the empty field

Comment: I've added an edit to explain a little more

Comment: Call Forward is the name of a checkbox group and msisdnonBusy is the value for Busy (input field), which, when is checked, it becomes editable and stores a value. I've tried to make an adaptation of this explanation but without results.

Comment: Can you break out and post an stripped-down example of what you're trying to do please? I.e. the html with the form containing only the checkbox/input and validation code etc. It'll make it easier to see what you're trying to do